# How to import .sqlite file to sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to import .sqlite file to sqlite3 im using windows 8 pc,
It's throwing an error of

> expected 5 rows found 1-rest filled with null

even my table columns are fine.

can anyone please help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you try to import the file? (Usually .sqlite is already the database format, not SQL suitable for import.)  Can you show the content of your .sqlite file?

Comment: if I do .read <filename>.sqlite it's reading but some unwanted characters also coming with this

Comment: That does not look like SQL but more like the binary storage format of sqlite. In that case you don't have to import it, but can use it as a database directly.

Comment: ya thanks a lot, can you please help me to use this directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a third party tool called SQLite Database Browser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser).

Using the sqlite browser, open your database in old format (.sqlite) and then click **File -> Export -> Database to SQL file.**

Now, close the database. Create a new database using SQLite Browser (it automatically generates the database in the new SQLite3 format). Once a database is created, use the **File -> Import -> Database to SQL file** into the new database in SQLite3 format.

Comment: no my theme is I just want to read this .sqlite file from my php code.

Comment: If you are using the old .sqlite then try this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php otherwise, what you want this is this: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try this method. So you don't have to import/export via third-party files such as csv or any additional software. I plan to do this method to periodically copy aquired data in a RAMDRIVE-placed database to the SD-Card. Of course sqlite3 must be able to load your database in your case.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'foo.sqlite' AS 'foo';
.databases

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'main.mytable' SELECT * FROM 'foo.mytable';
DETACH DATABASE 'foo';
.databases
```

check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_attach_database.htm) for ATTACH syntax and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for more INSERT variations.

Answer (score 1):

You use the PHP sqlite API to use an .sqlite database.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

In general you supply the path to your .sqlite file in the sqlite_open() call, see for an example the manual page of sqlite_open:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php